# bundle install in Capistrano not installing assets gems in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, bundler

When I run `cap deploy`, the gems in the `:assets` group are not installed.

This is a problem because I'm using precompiled assets, and Capistrano has to run `rake assets:precompile` on the server. That will fail unless the assets gems are installed.

I can work around this problem by manually running `bundle install` within the correct release directory. But obviously this isn't the proper workflow.

Here's the full command Capistrano is executing to install the gems on each deploy:

```
rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cd 
/home/deploy/rails_apps/vlc/releases/20120223192328 && bundle install --gemfile 
/home/deploy/rails_apps/vlc/releases/20120223192328/Gemfile --path 
/home/deploy/rails_apps/vlc/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'
```

Here's the end, which I think might be part of the problem:

```
--deployment --quiet --without development test'
```

Evidently, these flags cause Bundler to install without the `:assets` group. What is the expected behavior here? Is what I'm seeing out of the ordinary? (I'm guessing so, since it doesn't make sense for Capistrano to deliberately refrain from installing a gem group that it's about to use.)

As a side note, I also note this line in `application.rb`:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

I'm assuming nothing in `application.rb` would affect a `bundle install`, since Rails doesn't boot for that. But please correct me if this line is actually relevant to my problem.

Comment: What does your `Gemfile` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--without` is remembered option, check in your project dir / on server the file `.bundle/config` it's possible it already contains something like this:

```
---
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: assets
```